# C# HashSet generating System.OutOfMemoryException sporadically but reproducibly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

So we have two projects - a core project which we can call MainProject that has a function called `LoadData()` that loads 33,751,107 string text records into a `HashSet` one at a time, and a Unit Test project which we can call TestProject which runs a unit test against `LoadData` (it references MainProject).

If we run the unit test in TestProject, it passes and loads all 33,751,107 records successfully with no errors.

However, if we run the LoadData() function during startup of MainProject, it crashes with this exception:

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Interestingly, it crashes after successfully loading 23,986,243 records and then attempting to load the next batch.

This is very strange.  How can the `LoadData` function crash in MainProject (which is an ASP.NET 4.6.1 web project) and **NOT** crash in TestProject (which is .NET Framework 4.7.2 unit test project, using MSTest framework) which simply runs the same `LoadData` function?

I even tried upgrading MainProject to ASP.NET 4.7.2 (which had no effect, still crashes).  There is nothing special in web.config for MainProject, or in app.config for TestProject.  I tried adding this to web.config:

`<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true"/>`

This did not change or fix the problem.  The behavior is not random, or intermittent - it happens reproducibly every time.  I'm out of ideas.

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: I tried creating a SuperHashSet class that creates a collection of multiple HashSets each with a max item count of 10,000,000 items.  This dies with the same error, at exactly the same point, even though it is using ~3+ HashSets instead of one big one.  Any ideas?

Comment: How much memory do those 23,986,243 records need?

Comment: So it's always after that amount of records? What happens if you reverse/shuffle the orders before loading?

Comment: Are you running both on the same machine?

Comment: @zaitsman Yes I am running both on the same machine

Comment: @Martheen Good question, I will try reversing and see what happens and report back

Comment: @AntonínLejsek MainProject requires approximately 3 GB (that is how much RAM the process .exe is using) to load the 23M records.  When I run the unit test TestProject, the peak RAM usage of the process is 5 GB (this loads all of the items successfully).

Comment: Have you set [`gcAllowVeryLargeObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element) under proper parent nodes?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski It is set under configuration > runtime - is that correct?

Comment: I am now thinking maybe I should make a collection of HashSets and limit the size of each to about 20M entries.  At my current dataset size I would only need 2 or 3 of them.  Still would like to know why HashSet itself has so many issues though.

Comment: Ensure that MainProject is x64

Comment: @GiddyNaya I have x64 set in the toolbar at the top of Visual Studio.  Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Have you tried executing the MainProject outside of Visual Studio? e.g Loading the executable directly from debug folder.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @GiddyaNaya for the answer - the issue was that the project was not building as x64.  Once going through all the configuration settings, I found that deep down 2 levels it was still set to Any CPU.  Thanks again for your help on this.